# Why nodes are not getting created even after giving admin access in AWS IAM?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops, amazon-iam, amazon-eks

I have created EKS Cluster using eksctl tool Now I have checked cluster using
`eksctl get nodegroup --cluster MyCluster-name.` 
Now I am trying list the nodegroup but getting [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1r5K.jpg) & `[this][2]` in EKS Dashboard

I have arched below policies:-

- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- IAMFullAccess
- AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
- AmazonVPCFullAccess
- AmazonEKSServicePolicy

eks_use_eks_cfn

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

eks_user_eks_policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "eks:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Configured aws credentials using `aws configure`

***Even after adding AdministratorAccess I am getting above error

The YAML I am using to create Cluster is

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name:  two-node-group
  region: us-east-1
nodeGroups:
  - name: ng--1 #My-Nodegroup_1
    instanceType: t2.micro
    desiredCapacity: 1
    ssh:
      publickey: key2
  - name: ng--2 #My_nodegroup_2
    maxSize: 2
    minsize: 1
    instancesDistribution:
    instanceTypes: [ "t2.micro", "t2.micro" ]
    maxPrice: 0.1
    onDemandBaseCapacity: 0 
    onDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity: 50 
    ssh:
      publickey: key2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be related to either user permissions not being propagated accurately or this [issue](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/1578).

To replicate your scenario, I create an IAM user with the following policies attached:

- AmazonEKSClusterPolicy
- AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
- AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
- AmazonEKSServicePolicy
- AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy
- AmazonEKSVPCResourceController
- AdministratorAccess

First, I created the cluster by running the following command:

```
> eksctl create cluster -n test-cluster --nodes-min 1 --nodes-max 1 --instance-types t4g.small
...
2 sequential tasks: { create cluster control plane "test-cluster",
    2 sequential sub-tasks: {
        wait for control plane to become ready,
        create managed nodegroup "ng-ebe84d71",
    }
}
...
```

Afterwards, I was able to run the following command successfully:

```
CLUSTER         NODEGROUP       STATUS  CREATED                 MIN SIZE        MAX SIZE        DESIRED CAPACITY       INSTANCE TYPE    IMAGE ID        ASG NAME                                                TYPE
test-cluster    ng-ebe84d71     ACTIVE  2022-08-16T08:00:49Z    1               1               1                      t4g.small        AL2_ARM_64      eks-ng-ebe84d71-84c152d5-aca2-c498-e5d6-822ead3d6560    managed
```

As a summary, I would recommend the following:

- Check the IAM entry you are using to configure your `aws cli` locally - I would even try generating a new access token after you updated the IAM roles & policies attached to it
- Check CloudFormation for any rollback stacks that are failing as indicated [here](https://github.com/weaveworks/eksctl/issues/1578)

**EDIT1**
I tried replicating your process locally, and created a file with your exact configuration, just in a different region:

```
apiVersion: eksctl.io/v1alpha5
kind: ClusterConfig
metadata:
  name:  two-node-group
  region: eu-central-1
nodeGroups:
  - name: ng--1 #My-Nodegroup_1
    instanceType: t2.micro
    desiredCapacity: 1
    ssh:
      publickey: key2
  - name: ng--2 #My_nodegroup_2
    maxSize: 2
    minsize: 1
    instancesDistribution:
      instanceTypes: [ "t2.micro", "t2.micro" ]
      maxPrice: 0.1
      onDemandBaseCapacity: 0
      onDemandPercentageAboveBaseCapacity: 50
    ssh:
      publickey: key2
```

I then attached the following IAM policies to the user and I was able to create the cluster via `eksctl create cluster -f setup.yaml`:

- AmazonSSMFullAccess
- AmazonEC2FullAccess
- IAMFullAccess
- AmazonVPCFullAccess
- AmazonCloudFormationFullAccess
- EKSAdministrator

EKSAdministrator is a custom policy - please find below its JSON definition:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "EKSAdministrator",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "eks:*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: No it is not working even using Admin Access.  Not sure why you have used eksctl crerate cluster because for large environment it is not recommended.

Comment: Also I have added the YAML that I am using to create Cluster

Comment: These policies I am using
eks_use_eks_cfn
eks_user_eks_policy
AmazonEC2FullAccess
IAMFullAccess
AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy
AmazonVPCFullAccess
AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy
AmazonEKSFargatePodExecutionRolePolicy
AmazonEKSVPCResourceController

Comment: I used `eksctl create` because that is how you mentioned it at the beginning of your post: "I have created EKS Cluster using eksctl tool [...]" . Therefore, I assumed you created it via the eksctl CLI. In terms of IAM policies, I would also recommend to check this link that contains the minimum IAM policies required by eksctl: https://eksctl.io/usage/minimum-iam-policies/ I updated my answer to include the exact list of IAM policies I needed to be able to create your cluster with your YAML file